# Ruby Put Periodic Progress Messages While Mapping

Tags: ruby, dictionary, progress

I am mapping an array of items, but the collection can be quite large.  I would like to put a message to console every so often, to give an indication of progress.  Is there a way to do that during the mapping process?

This is my map statement:

```
famgui = family_items.map{|i|i.getGuid}
```

I have a def that I use for giving an update when I am doing a for each or while loop.

This is the def:

```
def doneloop(saymyname, i)
    if (i%25000 == 0 )
        puts "#{i} #{saymyname}"
    end
end
```

I normally put x = 0 before I start the loop, then x +=1 once I am in the loop and then at the end of my loop, I put `saymyname = "specific type items gathered at #{Time.now}"`
Then I put `doneloop(saymyname, x)`

I am not sure how to do that when I am mapping, as there is no loop to construct this around.  Does anyone have a method to give updates when using map?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can map with index:

```
famgui = family_items.with_index.map {|item, index| item.getGuid; doneloop('sth', index)}
```

Comment: You need to change the order of statements in your block, right now you're returning the value of doneloop, not the GUID.

Comment: Is this right? 
saymyname = "family items gathered at #{mytime(Time.now)}"
famgui = family_items.with_index.map {doneloop(saymyname, index);|item, index| item.getGuid}

Comment: Or maybe this 

`saymyname = "family items gathered at #{mytime(Time.now)}"
famgui = family_items.with_index.map {|index,item| item.getGuid;doneloop(saymyname, index)}`

Answer (score 2):

Only the last expression is returned from a map, so you can do something like:

```
famgui = family_items.with_index.map do |i, idx| 
  if idx % 100 == 0 
    puts # extra linefeed
    # report every 100th round
    puts "items left: #{family_items_size - idx}"
    STDOUT.flush
  end
  current_item += 1 
  print "."
  STDOUT.flush
  i.getGuid
end
```

This will print "." for each item and a status report after every 100 items.

If you want, you can use `each_with` and populate the array yourself like:

```
famgui = []
family_items.each_with_index do |i, idx|
  famgui << i.getGuid
  puts "just did: #{idx} of #{family_items.size}"
end
```

Comment: I am mapping over 4 million items, so I definitely don't want to print . for each item.  I am finding that the bigger issue in what I am doing is a utility, which is taking all the memory and forever to run.

Comment: that was just an example.

Comment: instead of flushing your STDOUT each time you can just once STDOUT.sync = true